# Cognos reports multiple comments

Tags: cognos

I have a report that returns comments added from a user on a Work Order, however, it only shows the first comment.  How can I set up the report so that it will show all comments, including date/time stamps?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a Work Order Table and a seperate comments table, in a header/detail relationship?

IE. WORK_ORDER table has a WO_NUMBER field
    WORK_ORDER_COMMENTS table has a corresponding WO_NUMBER, then multiple records per work order, one record for each comment?

If that is the situation, then that relationship is defined in framework manager.  It should be something like '1 to n' records, and 'n to 1', such that the Work Order table has 1 record and the Work Order Comments table has n records.

If their relationship is defined '1 to 1' then Cognos will grab the first comment it finds for a Work Order, and return 1 comment per work order.

If you can, please provide more details, such as What version of Cognos you are using, what the tables/key fields are, and how they are mapped in your framework manager.